# Vinyl covered cabinets

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

I just removed the vinyl laminate from my kitchen cabinets. I've been trying to scrape off all the glue but it's been a project. Is there anything else I can remove the glue with? Sanding only melts the glue so I've been scraping it off with a small spatula. I have the primer and paint already, Sherwin Williams helped me pick out the best paint to cover them with. Does all the glue have to be off before I prime?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want all of the adhesive off before you paint. If you want a non-chemical alternative, you can scrape off the majority a lot easier if you heat it up with a heat gun or a hair dryer.  This is basically what your sander is doing through friction, except the melted adhesive is sticking to the sandpaper and smearing instead of coming off.

After you get the bulk of it off, the remaining residue can be stripped off with an [adhesive eraser wheel](https://www.google.com/#q=Adhesive+Eraser+Wheel&tbm=shop) in an electric drill (do this outside, it will make a mess). This is essentially the same thing as the belt cleaner @paperstreet recommends - just powered by a drill instead of an elbow. Auto supply stores would be a good place to look for one.

Finish up by sanding with 120 or 150 grit sandpaper followed by 220 grit.

BTW, I hope that you told Sherwin Williams you were painting MDF and that they didn't give you a water based primer - these can raise the fibers in MDF and make it practically impossible to sand out.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with acetone or mineral spirits and a scraper to get the adhesive film gone. You would have better luck with a sander if you used a very heavy grit of paper, 36grit or 40 grit would probably work for you but you risk gouging your cabinets. The best solution for you is a chemical called Methyl Ethyl Keytone. ( usually referred to by its acronym M.E.K.) You may be able to find it at your local hardware store. I buy it by the gallon at Sherwin Williams.

NOTE: This is a very volatile chemical. It should be used with proper respiration or in a ventilated area. handle it with gloves. You can apply it with a rag, give it a few minutes and scrape or wipe the residue off with a damp rag. This will give you the results you are looking for in lightning quick time. After the film is removed be sure to sand from 120 to 300 grit for a smooth clean finish.

Best of luck!

Comment: What about MDF cabinets? They're not wood.

Comment: Will the methyl ethyl keytone eat away at the MDF?

Comment: This is a long row to hoe but one trick to get contact adhesive off (I'm assuming your adhesive is a contact or something similar) is to rub it with a belt cleaner: